# ios what is wrong with my simple loop?

Tags: objective-c, ios, for-loop

```
NSMutableArray *noDup = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *dup = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (NSString *first in newsmall)
{
    BOOL hasfound = NO;
    //NSLog (@"first %@", first);

    for (NSString *second in newbig) 
    {
        //NSLog (@"second %@", second);
        if ([second isEqualToString:first])
        {
            [dup addObject:first];
            hasfound = YES;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!hasfound)
    {
        //NSLog (@"has not found %@", first);
        [noDup addObject:first];
    }
}
```

newsmall is a small array of only strings and newbig is a big array of only strings. The app shuts itself without any debug warning. `NSLog` showed "first" and "second", but not "has not found". How come?

Comment: "not has not found" - I'm confused by that statement.  Is your question that your `dup` array never ends up with any entries even if there are matching strings in first and second?

Comment: I compare string from newsmall with string from newbig, and I want to save string from newsmall if it has not matched with any string from newbig.

Comment: @michael actually both arrays are same, except in that newbig has some extra strings at the end.

Comment: Are you sure your strings are of the same case, and there are no leading/trailing blanks?  Did you put an NSLog inside the inner `if` to see if maybe everything's going through that path for some strange reason?

Comment: In this case `hasfound ` will has always the value of `YES` and the if statement will equal to `NO`. That mean the code inside the if statement will never be reached. This is normal in you case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, duhhhhh.  I understand your problem now.

Reverse the order in which your arrays are being compared.  If you want to find which strings in newbig do not exist in newsmall, iterate across newbig first while looking to see which enumerated word in newbig exists in newsmall.

The code looks like this (and only two lines of code have changed):

```
NSMutableArray *noDup = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *dup = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (NSString *first in newbig)
{
    BOOL hasfound = NO;
    //NSLog (@"first %@", first);

    for (NSString *second in newsmall) 
    {
        //NSLog (@"second %@", second);
        if ([second isEqualToString:first])
        {
            [dup addObject:first];
            hasfound = YES;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!hasfound)
    {
        //NSLog (@"has not found %@", first);
        [noDup addObject:first];
    }
}
```

See the subtle difference?

Comment: I'm glad to have been able to help you out!

Comment: Um, I tested it now, and it does not work. I replaced isEqualToString: with hasPrefix: Does it matter? It showed all "noDup" from newbig, but nothing in "dup". I must be foggy in my head....

Comment: By the way, this for loop which I made and your rewritten for loop do not do what I want to achieve. I want to add a string (second) from newbig to dup, when strings from both array match and add a string (first) that does not exist in newbig in noDup.

Comment: sorry again, I figured it out. It was my fault that I didnt separate my array properly. By the way how should I add string "second" in if(!hasfound) statement instead of "first"?

Comment: if you want to add in `second`, you'll have to move your `NSString * second` declaration out of that for-loop context.  I.E. declare `NSString * second` within the first for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop can be replaced with containsObject: method as follows:

```
for (NSString *first in newbig) {
    if ([newsmall containsObject:first]) {
        [dup addObject:first];
    } else {
        [noDup addObject:first];
    }
}
```

Also, converting newsmall to a NSSet will increase speed.